# ¿How to count the number of json files in a folder with flutter?

Tags: json, flutter, listview

I'm learning flutter and I'm trying to build an app, where the user creates his own gym routines, I was thinking of saving each routine in a json file, so I want to create a ListView, where each ListTile is a routine. My problem is that, in order to do that, I would need to know the number of json files in the folder and their names, and I don't know how to do that (or if it's even possible). What do you recommend? Maybe there is a better way of doing what I want. Thank you!

Comment: You can just create a 1 JSON file and create an array of routines. Sample: `{"routines": [{"routine1": {}}, {"routine2": {}}]}`

Comment: Yeah, I thought of that, it's just that one routine has a lot of information and one file with all of the routines would be impossible to read and very difficult to handle